# show that $\{\,a+xf(x) \mid a \in 2\mathbb Z, f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]\,\}$ is a nonprincipal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: show that $\{\,a+xf(x) \mid a \in 2\mathbb Z, f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]\,\}$ is an not an princial ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$

My attempt: 
I first showed that 
$\{\,a+xf(x) \mid a \in 2\mathbb Z, f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]\,\}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Then,

$$\langle x^{2}, 2\rangle = \{\,a+xf(x) \mid a \in 2\mathbb Z, f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]\,\} $$

1. $\langle x^{2}, 2\rangle\subset\langle f(x)\rangle$
   Hence, $f(x)$ should be $1$.

Then $\langle f(x)\rangle  = \mathbb Z[X]$.

1. $\langle f(x)\rangle\subset\langle x^{2}, 2\rangle$

$x+2\in\langle f(x)\rangle$

but $x+2$ is not $\in\langle x^2,2\rangle$

Is my attempt correct?

Could you help me please?

Comment: Where did the $x^2$ come from? Also, it seems like a bad idea to use $f(x)$ in two places, with different meanings.

Comment: First of all, note that $x\in \{\,a+xf(x)\mid a\in 2\mathbb Z, f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]\,\}$, hence this ideal is $\ne\langle x^2,2\rangle$. Actually, it is $\langle x,2\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

First, see if you can prove the equality $\langle x,2\rangle=\{a+xf(x)\mid a\in2\mathbb{Z},\;f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}$.  Next, notice if $\langle x,2\rangle$ were generated by a single element, it would have to divide $2$, so there are only four possibilities (remember negatives), none of which will work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove the equality! Does it use that A=B when A $\subset B$ and B $\subset$ A?

Comment: @user88310: Sure.  That is a great way to prove the equality of two sets.

Comment: I'm not sure why <x,2> is not a principal ideal. For example, why not <x,2> = <2>?

Comment: Is it because 2+x is not in <2>?

Comment: @user88310: Sure, that is one way to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct.  I don't know how you concluded that $\langle x^2, 2\rangle$ is equal to the ideal that you are considering, but this is incorrect.  In fact you have shown that it is incorrect when you state that $x + 2 \notin \langle x^2, 2\rangle$.  In fact your ideal is $\langle x, 2\rangle$.

To prove your statement use the degree of $f(x)$ to show that if $f(x)$ divides $2$ then it must be degree $0$, i.e., it must be an integer.  Then if $f(x)$ also divides $x$ what must that integer be?

Answer (score 0):

$\langle x,2 \rangle$ is the same ideal as $\langle x \rangle + \langle 2 \rangle$. Actually, one can easily prove that if $I = \langle S \rangle$ and $J = \langle T \rangle$ then $I+J = \langle S \cup T \rangle$. And sum of ideals is an ideal. This is an easy exercise that you must prove. You should know operations on ideals very well because it's very useful.

For showing that it is not principal, assume that it is principal. Then there must exist an element $z$ such that $\langle 2,x \rangle = \langle z \rangle$. But then $2,x \in \langle z \rangle$ and this means that $z|2$ and $z|x$. From $z|2$ it's implied that $z=\pm 1$ or $z=\pm 2$. But if $z= \pm 1$ then $\langle z\rangle = \langle 1 \rangle = Z[x]$ but $\langle x, 2 \rangle \neq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ because $3 \notin \langle 2,x \rangle$, therefore $z=\pm 2$. But if $2|x$ then there exists $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = p(x)\cdot 2$. Hence, $deg(x) = deg(p(x))+deg(2) \implies 1 = deg(p(x)) + 0 \implies deg(p(x))=1$.  So, we must have $2(a+bx) = x$, this results in $a=0$ and $b=1/2$, but $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b=1/2$ is not acceptable. That's a contradiction. Hence, $\langle 2,x \rangle$ is not principal.